# Functions and Pointer help: Program builds but Crashes without any specific errors

Tags: c++, c

I'm working on a hw assignment and I keep getting a crash but I don't get any errors It just crashes instead. I created 2 functions to try to calculate the max,min and avg and 1 to generate 3 random numbers and send it back to main. All my values from my functions need to be returned as pointers. Thanks for the help in advanced!

```
int * random_number()
{
     static int num[3];
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

         num[i] = (10 + rand() % 90);
     }
     return num;
}

int * calculate(int *value)
{
    static int ans[3];
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ans[0] += value[i];
        ans[0] = ans[0] / i;
        if (value[i] > max)
        {
            ans[2] = max;
        }
        int min = value[0];
        if (value[i] < min)
        {
            ans[3] = min;
        }
    }
    return ans;

}



int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int cnt = 0;
    int *result;
    int *find;

    do{
        result = random_number();
        find = calculate(result);
        cnt++;
    }


    while(cnt < 10);
        if (cnt == 10){
            printf("Result is %i, %i, %i.", result[0],result[1],result[2]);
            printf("The avg is %i. The max is %i and the min is %i.", find[0], find[1], find[2]);

            printf("Worked \n");
        }
        else
            printf("Didn't work");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `calculate()` is buggy (several ways).  The crash is probably the divide by zero from `ans[0] = ans[0] / i;` in the first loop pass.

Comment: Try using a debugger to debug the code. It will show you where the program crashed. Also, is this C or C++?

Comment: Run it in a debugger. Step through it line by line - observe variable values (and stack trace) and you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your `calculate()` function has a number of bugs -- mainly that you are trying to do some things within your `for` loop that should be done outside it.  The crash you're getting is from the line:

```
        ans[0] = ans[0] / i;
```

...when `i` is zero on the first loop pass (so you're dividing by zero).  That division should actually be done *after* the loop, after all the values have been added (and will always be a divide by 3).

The line:

```
         int min = value[0];
```

should be moved to before the loop as well; as it is, you're resetting the value of `min` on every loop pass, so you're actually ending up with the *last* value that's less than `value[0]`, if there is one... and you don't change `ans[3]` at all when there isn't.  `ans[3]` should actually be `ans[2]` anyway... `ans[3]` is out of bounds (would be the 4th element).

Comment: Didn't see the mistake with `min` in there.

Comment: Ohhh okay thank you so much! :D

Comment: @AndyHo you need to set initial values for the array elements.  As the array is static, they should be zero before the first call to the function, but after that they retain the values from the previous call.  I'd set them all to `value[0]` before the loop, then start the loop from 1 instead of zero... and get rid of `min` and just use `ans[2]` instead, and get rid of `max` and use `ans[1]` instead.